# Python re can't split zero-width anchors?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

s = 'PythonCookbookListOfContents'

# the first line does not work
print re.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', s ) 

# second line works well
print re.sub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', ' ', s)

# it should be ['Python', 'Cookbook', 'List', 'Of', 'Contents']
```

How to split a string from the border of a lower case character and an upper case character using Python re?

Why does the first line fail to work while the second line works well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

> Note that split will never split a string on an empty pattern match.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> >>> re.split('x*', 'foo')
> ['foo']
> >>> re.split("(?m)^$", "foo\n\nbar\n")
> ['foo\n\nbar\n']
> ```

---

How about using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead? (Instead of focusing on separators, focus on the item you want to get.)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'PythonCookbookListOfContents'
>>> re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]+', s)
['Python', 'Cookbook', 'List', 'Of', 'Contents']
```

**UPDATE**

Using [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (*Alternative regular expression module, to replace re*), you can split on zero-width match:

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'PythonCookbookListOfContents'
>>> regex.split('(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])', s, flags=regex.VERSION1)
['Python', 'Cookbook', 'List', 'Of', 'Contents']
```

**NOTE**: Specify `regex.VERSION1` flag to enable split-on-zero-length-match behavior.

Comment: Of course I can use findall to find words, but how to split them just according to the border of upper and lower cases? You need to handle this question one day when the situation changed and you have to use zero-width anchors to match borders.

Comment: By anchor you mean array ?

Comment: I mean look ahead and look behind, namely ‘?<=’ and ‘?=’ . @Onilol

Comment: @Booster, I updated the answer accordingly. (to mention `regex` non-standard module)

Comment: Wow, this works well. So, you mean this module is better than the standard re module?

Comment: @Booster, Please follow the link and see the features that standard `re` modules doesn't provide.

Comment: PyPi regex module is more than better than `re`. It even supports an infinite-width lookbehind as .NET, and keeps a capture collection, same way as in .NET.

Comment: @Booster - Yeah, be careful how you use `import regex` as they went berserk with new constructs, that may foul up existing other regex.

Comment: I came here looking for an answer, and using `re.findall` instead of `re.split` did the trick for me. Thanks! The expression is more complex using `re.findall` but is not totally unmanageable. I also don't need an extra dependency to use this solution.